# how frequently check mongoose connection status nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to check the mongoose package connection string status dynamically after instance start, like npm start.

I tried this method,

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  if(mongoose.connection.readyState == 1){
    mongoStatus = true;
  }else{
    mongoStatus = false;
  }
}, 2000);
```

but i need mongoose predefined events?

NOTE: I am trying to create a custom circuit breaker for all services so that i need to check frequently the status

Comment: Could you explain more why you want to do this? Is it because you don't want to initiate something until mongoose successfully connected?

Comment: I am trying to create a custom circuit breaker for all services so I need this,
circuit breaker like https://www.npmjs.com/package/hystrixjs

Comment: Can you use [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection-events)?
`mongoose.connection.on('error' | 'disconnecting' | 'disconnected' | 'close', event => { mongoStatus = false // or whatever you want to do })`

Comment: @Jonathan Nielsen thank you so much its working as expected!!

Comment: Awesome, I added an answer which you can mark as the solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [Connection events](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection-events) in Mongoose.

```js
mongoose.connection.on('error' | 'disconnecting' | 'disconnected' | 'close', event => {
  mongoStatus = false // Or whatever you want to do
})
```

Comment: If the Mongo cluster itself goes down, when will `disconnect` be triggered? In other words, does Mongoose do any type of connection heartbeat?